# autofs mounting without passwords

Tags: mount, autofs

I have an existing `autofs` Centos-Centos mount. I forgot how I set those up without having to require a password.

```
# /etc/auto.folder
folder -fstype=nfs,rw 10.10.10.1:/folder
```

Now, I'm trying to setup another mount but I get access denied.

```
# /etc/auto.folder
folder        -fstype=nfs,rw 10.10.10.1:/folder
anotherfolder -fstype=nfs,rw 10.10.10.2:/anotherfolder
```

Manual `mount` of `anotherfolder` expects a password while `folder` doesn't. Is whitelisting a server/folder possible?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Feeling so dumb right now. It was because `anotherfolder` wasn't in the `/etc/exports` on the source machine. I added it an did a reload and the client was allowed to mount it.

```
# /etc/exports
/path/to/anotherfolder 10.10.10.9(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)

# reload
exports -r
```